# How do I enable the backlit keyboard on an ASUS G53SX or G53SW?

Tags: keyboard, asus, backlight

Does anyone know how to enable backlit keyboard on ASUS G53SX?

Edit as of Feb 18, 2012: As Qw4z1 mentioned here's a trick to enable the backlit brightness:

```
su
(enter root password)
echo 0x00050021 > /sys/kernel/debug/asus-nb-wmi/dev_id
echo 0x82 > /sys/kernel/debug/asus-nb-wmi/ctrl_param
cat /sys/kernel/debug/asus-nb-wmi/devs
exit
```

Comment: Any news mate??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does it for me:

```
echo 0x00050021 > /sys/kernel/debug/asus-nb-wmi/dev_id
echo 0x82 > /sys/kernel/debug/asus-nb-wmi/ctrl_param
cat /sys/kernel/debug/asus-nb-wmi/devs
```

Can't seem to find a better solution for G53SX. Doesn't seem to work after a reboot though, so maybe run att startup or keep it in a file that you can run when it's dark. =)

Found it here: [Notebookreview](http://forum.notebookreview.com/asus-gaming-notebook-forum/553474-g73-asus-wmi-linux-driver-i-need-your-help-6.html#post7470992)

Answer (score 2):

Try function F4 to turn the brightness up on the keypad.